# How can I set multiple attributes on a firebase object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, firebase-realtime-database

I am using a library called [redux-firebasev3](https://github.com/prescottprue/redux-firebasev3) to make three separate set calls to firebase.

```
for(let object of array) {
    ....
    firebase.set(`/object/${id}/attr1`, attr1);
    firebase.set(`/object/${id}/attr2`, attr2);
    firebase.set(`/object/${id}/attr3`, attr3);
}
```

The array has a length of 32. When it gets to about the 8th to the last object chrome dev tools freeze up and crash. Is there a better way I should be making these calls? What could be the reason for the failure? I can't see errors because dev tools crash.

[Here is the link to set function in the library.](https://github.com/prescottprue/redux-firebasev3/blob/master/API.md#setpath-value-oncomplete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but are you looking for this?

```
firebase.set(`/object/${id}`, { attr1: attr1, , attr2: attr2, attr3: attr3 });
```

Comment: Yes, I had just wanted suggestions for better ways of making three calls. That it would hopefully speed it up and less prone to crashing.

Comment: Will this override the other attributes on the object. Say it has an attribute 4 and you don't need to set it. Will it only have three attributes after this call?

Comment: The speed up you'll gain from combining calls will be minimal, since [Firebase pipelines these requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786). But the update will be atomic on the wire, which means that up `attr1` is invalid (according to your security rules), the entire `set()` will fail in my variant.

Comment: Yes, calling `set()` will overwrite all data at the location. If you want to update the properties, call `update()`. I highly recommend that you check out [Firebase's JavaScript guid](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/save-data) and [reference docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database), which covers a lot of these cases.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Frank!

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** I am one of the author's of [redux-firebasev3](https://github.com/prescottprue/redux-firebasev3)

Not sure if I understand the original question, but to clarify:

To set multiple attributes in one object all at once:

`` firebase.set(`/object/${id}`, { attr1: "some val", attr2: "some string", attr3: "some other" }); ``

To set multiple attributes to **multiple separate** locations:

`` firebase.set(`/messages/${id}`, {
  attr1: "some val",
  attr2: "some string"
})
firebase.set(`/objects/${id}`, {
  attr1: "some val",
  attr2: "some string"
}) ``

To set update an **existing path**:

`` firebase.update(`/messages/${id}`, {
  attr1: "some val",
  attr2: "some string"
}) ``

The goal was to have the library as closley mirror [the Firebase API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/save-data) as possible, including things like set and update.

The repo now includes examples like the [simple example](https://github.com/prescottprue/redux-firebasev3/tree/master/examples/simple)